# 3 consecutive chars with letters in between

Tags: java, if-statement, char

I am trying to see find all words that have the characters "d" + "a" + "t" in the words, in that same order, but there could be space in between. for example.. redundant...it has d, a, and t, but there is a letter between the series. I have this right now and I have no idea what else to do.

```
static void mainTest (){

  String[] words = WordTool.getDictionary ();
  int count = 0;
  System.out.println();

  for (int j = 0 ; j < words.length ; j++){

     if ( words[j].contains("d" + "a" + "t")){
         System.out.println(words[j]);
         count ++;
     }

  }
```

Comment: HINT: `indexOf("t") > indexOf("a") > indexOf("d")`, and none of them equal to `-1`.

Comment: @RohitJain great logic, but due to transitive properties of strictly greater than, you only would need to make sure the index of `d` is greater than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a regex, for example:

```
System.out.println("redundant".matches(".*d.*a.*t.*")); //prints true
```